# How to add custom map source to route-me?

Tags: iphone, dictionary

'route-me' is an iPhone map engine and I want to add my own map source to it. I've got all the map images on my server but I dont know how to add the map source? Any one could help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be two ways to do this:

First, from the documentation:

If you have your own maps, you can use [Mapnik](http://www.mapnik.org/) as a framework and [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) as your host. You can then point to your map with the `RMOpenStreetMapsSource` class to specify the URL.

Alternatively,

You can use an app for route-this called SimpleMap along with an extension called Map2sqlite. This allows you to use a class caled `RMDBTileSource` and point to a sqlite DB file of your maps as the source. I found this tidbit on a [google groups article covering this topic.](http://groups.google.com/group/route-me-map/browse_thread/thread/d4d5601b3cce5798/ea0c9e6885df5a17?lnk=gst&q=rmdbtilesource#ea0c9e6885df5a17)

Answer (score 4):

google maps in route-me example:

in RegionGmapTile.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RMAbstractMercatorWebSource.h"

@interface RegionGmapTile : RMAbstractMercatorWebSource 
{    
}

@end
```

in RegionGmapTile.m

```
#import "RegionGmapTile.h"


@implementation RegionGmapTile

-(NSString*) tileURL: (RMTile) tile
{


    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@127&x=%d&y=%d&z=%d",tile.x, tile.y,tile.zoom];
    return url;
} 

-(NSString*) uniqueTilecacheKey
{
    return @"NLSHistoricMap";
} 

-(NSString *)shortName
{
    return @"NLS Historic Map";
}
-(NSString *)longDescription
{
    return @"NLS Historic Map Test";
}
-(NSString *)shortAttribution
{
    return @"Google maps";
}
-(NSString *)longAttribution
{
    return @"Google maps";
} 


@end
```

somwehere in your route-me

```
[[RMMapContents alloc] initForView:mvMap];

mvMap.contents.tileSource = [[RegionGmapTile alloc] init];
```

and google maps are shown without any key

Answer (score 2):

So, code below should get the job done?

```
id <RMTileSource> tileSource;
NSURL *mapURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myOSM_URL"];
tileSource = [[[RMOpenStreetMapSource alloc] initWithURL:mapURL] autorelease];
```

Doing this results with error:

```
-[RMOpenStreetMapSource initWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b0c310
```